# can't find my packages from pycharm/heroku

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have deployed a package into https://pypi.org/project/core-lib/0.0.1.dev1/

But `pycharm` or `heroku` can't find my package with this error message

Can you help me, please?

Thank you

**Pycharm**

```
No matching package version found: 'core-lib==0.0.1.dev1' (required: ==0.0.1.dev1, installed: <nothing>, latest: <nothing>)
```

**heroku deploy**

```
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement core-lib==0.0.0.8 (from -r /tmp/build_c6b601b1/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for core-lib==0.0.0.8 (from -r /tmp/build_c6b601b1/requirements.txt (line 1))
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: What do you mean by PyCharm? Does it work if you install it locally, not through PyCharm?

Comment: inside the file `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Installed your package from pypi using PyCharm, and I am able to find it

```
   (randomtesting) C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\randomtesting>pip list
    Package                Version
    ---------------------- -------------------
    core-lib               0.0.1.dev1
```

Perhaps the file was released into pypi very recently?

And I checked the link again, now it has the latest version.
Maybe try this?

```
pip install core-lib
```

Comment: Thank you for testing. install using `pip install core-lib` have no issues. PyCharm will not autoinstall the missing dependencies.

Comment: solve the heroku problem with the `runtime.txt` update the python version

Comment: Ah, thanks for notifying. Btw, just to clarify, the result shown here is by using **core-lib==0.0.1.dev1**

Comment: I only found out there's newer version after testing

Comment: the only issue is PyCharm will not detect my package.

Answer (score 0):

You've [declared](https://github.com/shay-te/core-lib/blob/543db80706746a937e5ed16bd50f2de8d58b32e4/setup.py#L31) that your package must be used under Python >= 3.7. Please make sure you use Python with high enough version. For example, I tried to install the package with Python 2.7 and `pip` failed to find the project. With Python 3.7 it was installed successfully.